# Переключатель страниц для интернет магазина ucoz

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте! Я столнулся с проблемой капризной css модуля нетшопа в юКоЗ. Кто может, помогите сделать скрипт Назад и Далее.
Поясняю: кнопка Далее переключает на следующую страницу, а Назад соответственно возвращает на предыдущую.

Подобное есть на onliner.by/news внизу. Нужен такой же примерно переключатель! То есть не 1 2 3, а далее и назад.
Вот скрин этой кнопки
[image]

Comment: это не проблема CSS а проблема скрипта уже.

Comment: Помогите мне сделать тоже что у onliner.by

Comment: -1, Работа за автора.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про historyAPI браузера

```
history.back();
history.forward();
```